# Apache solr multi field indexing with django haystack

Tags: solr, django-haystack

I have a design problem in **django-haystack** that I don't know how to solve. In my django model, there is *a number of text fields* that I want index.
As far as I know from the official haystack documentation, the only way to index content is to merge everything you want to index in a single template.

The problem here is that I want to maintain a **per-field index**, i.e. I want to do a full-text search on each field separately or on a set of fields.

Is there a way do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to create additional CharFields?  The first tutorial page gives an example: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#handling-data for field author.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not my case. Other ``CharFields`` are just for faceting (like calling ``.objects.filter()`` through django), and only one field can be ``document=True``, which is a real index.

Comment: Or do they really allow a per-field index? Could you please give an example of a sample search query?

Comment: There are examples of querying multiple fields here: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#filter The basic idea is to pass multiple field/value pairs to QuerySet.filter().  All the fields are indexed (unless you have explicitly specified some stored/not indexed field).